# Similar Apps like DupeBlocker 3

Tags: appexchange, duplicate-management

We have a lot of duplicate data in our org (`Contacts`) and we want to clean up this data. I have come across an app called DupeBlocker 3. Are there similar apps which provide the same functionality and for a lesser price? Our company is a non-profit association.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this question is on topic.

We use an application called `Unique Entry` that seems to have the functionality you are looking for. Here is its [listing on the AppExchange](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000003KGFdEAO). I'm not sure about pricing, but it does say it's discounted for non-profits.